# Sailsjs session error

Tags: sails.js

Keep getting this warning & error when I lift my app and can't figure it out. Hoping someone has an idea about this:

> warn: Socket disconnected, but session could not be loaded to pass to configured disconnect handler: `sails.config.sockets.onDisconnect()`.  Will pass a fake, empty session as argument to lifecycle callback.  Details:
>    Error: Session could not be loaded
>       at _createError (/Users/JAT/Dropbox/Bottage/bottage_app/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:271:21)
>       at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/JAT/Dropbox/Bottage/bottage_app/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:274:13)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17) { [Error: Session could not be loaded] code: 'E_SESSION' }

---

**wZVanG Edit**: The problem is already fixed, however I wonder if I have the correct configuration:

**sailsrc** (I removed the models from `Sails` created by default because I just use `mongoose`), However the `sockets` I did not have to remove them:

```
"hooks": {"orm": false, "pubsub": false, "blueprints": false}
```

**/config/sessions.js**

```
adapter: 'mongo',
host: 'localhost',
port: 27017,
db: 'page',
collection: 'sessions',
```

**This stores it in my Mongo database:**

```
{
    "_id" : "Nt90RxTcHkOT9aM3qJ1QzxyHlnvFoUuw",
    "session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{}}",
    "expires" : ISODate("2015-07-24T10:59:42.551Z")
}
```

> It is correct?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the message is that when you restart sails the session info is deleted on the server side but the client side still has a session cookie and when it reconnects it reuses the previous session cookie to identify which is no longer valid and therefore the server logs this warning.

There are a number of ways to prevent this message:

1. Use an external session store such as redis which will detach the session data from sails and will keep it even when you restart sails. see here: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session
2. if socket.io is not required remove it from the project for removing the client side delete `assets/js/dependencies/sails.io.js` and sails.io.js include file in `tasks/pipeline.js` and for the server side

add this to `.sails.rc`:

```
  {
    "hooks": {
      "sockets": false,
      "pubsub": false 
     }
  }
```

3. just reopen the browser window which will start a new socket session

Comment: I am currently using `Sockets`, please, check my question **edit**.

Comment: Your configuration looks correct, one more thing to consider if using more then one instance for the app is to move the Socket.IO message store to mongo as well otherwise the sails instances won't be able to publish messages for clients connected between them. to do that install socket.io-adapter-mongo and add the following lines to `config/sockets.js`:
`adapter: 'socket.io-adapter-mongo',
  adapterOptions: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    db: 'mubsub'
  },`

Comment: What do you mean with more then one instance?. My server is hosted on Google Cloud (Ubuntu), I deploy multiple sites using different port like `8081, 8082, 8083`, with Nginx reverse proxy, that have something to do?

Comment: Multiple instances is if you have more then one process (on the same server or on different servers) running the same sails.js application at the same time, looks like this is the situation in the case you described.

Comment: thanks, I have not had a case using the sockets on different pages, but I'll try.